# VBA Formatting date and time

Tags: vba, powerbi

I'm trying to change a format of a time stamp in PowerBI Report Builder. The platform works with Microsoft Visual Basic. What i'm trying to do below is take the current time + 2 hours and convert it to the wanted format.

Wanted time works fine. For example DateAdd("h",2,Now()) returns 27/1/2022 08:48:30. However, i want it to be formatted as "27.1.2022 08:48:30 AM".

The code below does **not** work.

```
=Format(DateAdd("h",2,Now()), "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm")
```

as it returns `27.48.2022 08:48:30 a50/p50`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce that:

```
? Format(DateAdd("h",2,Now()), "d.m.yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm")
```

Gives: `27.1.2022 01:28:27 am`

If you don't want a zero-padded month then use `m` and not `mm`

Comment: Did you perform this procedure in PowerBI Report Builder or some other platform?